# Css display flex wrap around content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Can you make a `div` `display: flex` wrap around its dynamic content instead of spanning the whole page/container?

In this example the content is not dynamic, but let's assume it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  dduCard("card", "Header", "Wrap around this content", "Footer");
});

function dduCard(targetDivId, cHeader, cBody, cFooter) {
  var targetDiv = $("#" + targetDivId);

  var mainDiv = $("<div id='placeholder'/>");
  var headerDiv = $("<div id='headerrow'/>");
  var bodyDiv = $("<div id='bodyrow' />");
  var footerDiv = $("<div id='footerrow'/>");
  mainDiv.css({
    border: "1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.121569)",
    "border-radius": "4px",
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    color: "rgb(41,43,44)",
    display: "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "font-size": "16px",
    "line-height": "24px",
    "text-align": "center"
  });

  headerDiv.css({
    "border-bottom-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.121569)",
    "border-bottom-style": "solid",
    "border-bottom-width": "1px",
    "background-color": "rgb(247,247,249)",
    "border-radius": "3px 3px 0 0",
    display: "block",
    padding: "12px 20px"
  });
  bodyDiv.css({
    display: "block",
    "flex-basis": "auto",
    "flex-grow": "1",
    "flex-shrink": "1",
    "line-height": "24px",
    padding: "20px"
  });
  footerDiv.css({
    "border-top-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.121569)",
    "border-top-style": "solid",
    "border-top-width": "1px",
    "background-color": "rgb(247,247,249)",
    "border-radius": "3px 3px 0 0",
    display: "block",
    padding: "12px 20px"
  });

  headerDiv.append(cHeader);
  bodyDiv.append(cBody);
  footerDiv.append(cFooter);

  //    append
  mainDiv.append(headerDiv).append(bodyDiv).append(footerDiv);
  targetDiv.append(mainDiv);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="card">
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/dumitrudan608/pen/eEdPVG

Comment: Afternoon - please add your codepen as a code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: You want container to take all remaining height, yes?

Comment: An element wraps around its content by default... What is the question?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/87cf169b570e6b0fcdfd0c928ffcabee/  --- I'm not sure what you want to do, but I am sure that you should take most of that JS and put it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'wrap around' means, but I checked out the 'bootstrap card' that you mentioned - and amended your code to fit the bill. Does this help clarify the questions? https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/87cf169b570e6b0fcdfd0c928ffcabee/?editors=0010

### markup

```
<section class="cards">

  <ul class='card-list' id='card-list'>
    <!-- dynamic list items -->
  </ul>

</section>
```

### CSS

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 500px; /* arbitrary parent */
}

.card-list {

}

.card {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.card:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 1rem; 
}

.card .row {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card header {
  background: lightblue;
}

.card main {
  background: white;
}

.card footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

### scripts

```
var exampleData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    heading: "Card heading 1",
    body: "Card body 1",
    footer: "footer...",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    heading: "Card heading 2",
    body: "Card body 2",
    footer: "footer...",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    heading: "Card heading 3",
    body: "Card body 3",
    footer: "footer...",
  },
];

function buildCard(listName, headerCopy, mainCopy, footerCopy) {
  var $cardList = $('#' + listName);

  var $card = $("<li class='card'></li>");
  var $header = $("<header class='row header'></header>");
  var $main = $("<main class='row main'></main>");
  var $footer = $("<footer class='row footer'></footer>");

  // add content to rows
  $header.append(headerCopy);
  $main.append(mainCopy);
  $footer.append(footerCopy);

  // add rows to card
  $card.append($header).append($main).append($footer);
  $cardList.append($card);
}

$(document).ready( function() {

  // just to mock a server request for a 'list' of 'cards'
  exampleData.forEach( function(currentValue, currentIndex, fullArray) {
    var card = currentValue;
    buildCard('card-list', card.heading, card.body, card.footer);
  });

});
```